# Error when trying to create a pipenv using Python version 3.7 with system Python version 3.10.4

Tags: python, pipenv

I am trying to use Python 3.7 to run an old project that I found on GitHub that hasn't been active in a while. I am running this only Arch Linux where my system python version is 3.10.4. When I try to use `pipenv` to create a virtual environment. I get an error showed in this https://pastebin.com/ufVagUQa . The command that I run is

```
pipenv --python 3.7
```

Comment: I think you can use pyenv to manage your py version.

Comment: Please take the time to format the error message to something readable, each _letter_ of the log was on a separate line. I only parsed the last line of the error log which gives a clue: "*AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'*". It seems whichever module/library you are using does not yet support Python 3.10, which [removed `MutableMapping` from `collections`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70870087/2745495).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.