# AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping' (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pipenv, pipfile

On my ubuntu server I am trying to activate pipenv env.
When I type pipenv shell this comes out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pipenv==11.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 548, in shell
    from .import core
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

What's the matter?

Comment: `collections.MutableMapping` was moved to `collections.abc.MutableMapping` as of Python 3.10.  Your version of `requests` is old enough that it does not know about this change.  Update your `requests` package.

Comment: ```apt-get upgrade requests``` gives me ```Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package requests```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870041/cannot-import-name-mutablemapping-from-collections)

Comment: `requests` is typically installed via `pip`, not `apt-get`.

Comment: @user14473331 nope it doesn't

Comment: @JohnGordon ```Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (2022.6.15)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests) (2.1.1)```

Comment: All requirements are already satisfied tho. whats next?

Comment: What exact command did you type?  If you typed `pip install requests`, that won't _upgrade_ an older version you already have.

Comment: @JohnGordon pip install requests --upgrade

Comment: Are you using a python virtual environment?  And if so, did you type the pip command while you were inside the venv?

Comment: I am Pipfile in my directory. I am typing ```pipenv shell``` to activate it. It raises this error.

Comment: @JohnGordon ???