# How to solve the ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, importerror, dnspython

```
I was connecting the Python to mongoDB cluster.
But I got the error message 'importError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' in Python. I want to know how to solve this problem.

Here is my code

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://sparta:test@cluster0.59qgozp.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
db = client.PYTHON

doc = {
'name':'Kevin',
'age':24
```

}
db.user.insert_many(doc)

I tried to change db.user.insert_one to db.user.insert_many but both of them didn't work.
And I also tried to use Python 3.8.6 since I am using the 3.11.4.

Answer (score 0):

I see this has been on SO before, you could read more here. Maybe it might help you [cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870041/cannot-import-name-mutablemapping-from-collections)

Comment: Why was this down voted when SO gave the same answer after me?: `This question already has answers here:
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (3 answers)
Closed 22 hours ago.` I did the same as SO and before SO.  Did I not help? Or provide a useful answer as per guidelines to SO?