# Error while importing Pyspark on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a Jupyter notebook on UBUNTU in order to analyse data coming from HDFS by using PySpark. I have installed **Hadoop v3.2.1** & **spark v3.0.0** & **java8** & **python v3.10.12**
Here are my env variables :

```py
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
source ~/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f $(which java) | sed 's:bin/java::')
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```

When I run **pyspark** on the terminal, I get the jupyter notebook opened but when I type:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

I get the following error:

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

File /opt/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py:51
     48 import types
     50 from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
---> 51 from pyspark.context import SparkContext
     52 from pyspark.rdd import RDD, RDDBarrier
     53 from pyspark.files import SparkFiles

File /opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py:33
     31 from pyspark import accumulators
     32 from pyspark.accumulators import Accumulator
---> 33 from pyspark.broadcast import Broadcast, BroadcastPickleRegistry
     34 from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
     35 from pyspark.files import SparkFiles

File /opt/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py:24
     21 from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
     22 import threading
---> 24 from pyspark.java_gateway import local_connect_and_auth
     25 from pyspark.serializers import ChunkedStream, pickle_protocol
     26 from pyspark.util import _exception_message, print_exec

File /opt/spark/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py:33
     30 if sys.version >= '3':
     31     xrange = range
---> 33 from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, JavaObject, GatewayParameters
     34 from pyspark.find_spark_home import _find_spark_home
     35 from pyspark.serializers import read_int, write_with_length, UTF8Deserializer

File /opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:2496
   2490 register_output_converter(
   2491     proto.REFERENCE_TYPE,
   2492     lambda target_id, gateway_client: JavaObject(target_id, gateway_client))
   2494 if PY4J_SKIP_COLLECTIONS not in os.environ or\
   2495    os.environ[PY4J_SKIP_COLLECTIONS].lower() not in PY4J_TRUE:
-> 2496     __import__("py4j.java_collections")

File /opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/java_collections.py:13
      2 """
      3 Module responsible for converting Java collection classes to Python collection
      4 classes. This module is optional but loaded by default.
   (...)
      9 :author: Barthelemy Dagenais
     10 """
     11 from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
---> 13 from collections import (
     14     MutableMapping, Sequence, MutableSequence,
     15     MutableSet, Set)
     16 import sys
     18 from py4j.compat import (
     19     iteritems, next, hasattr2, isbytearray,
     20     ispython3bytestr, basestring)

ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Doing a quick search it appears that [ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870041/cannot-import-name-mutablemapping-from-collections) - this suggests there is a mismatch with versions of imports etc e.g. your pyspark install is on a version not compatible with your python (or another module) . A further search will probably yield more results.